# How can convert unknown video format to mp4

Tags: video, converters, mp4

How can convert proprietary video format X, unknown format for available converters, to mp4 format ?
someone make video by this format to force us to use own player!
is it possible? any app can do it? or by programming ?

Comment: Look into ffmpeg, it's one of the best tool available for video specific tasks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ffmpeg`.

`ffmpeg -i example.xyz example.mp4 -hide_banner`
will convert any (installed) video format to MP4.